# Transform.LookAt() changes object's Y rotation to 180 or -180

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a charge meter rotate around a pivot to face away from the mouse.

When I use `Transform.LookAt()`, the pivot's rotation is changed to 180 or -180.

What is the issue here and is there any way to solve this?

Code:

```
        public void Rotate(Vector3 direction)
        {
            if (direction.magnitude > 0)
            {
                var targetPosition = _pivot.position + direction;
                _pivot.LookAt(targetPosition, Vector3.up);
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

This is where I call the method mentioned above:

```
        private void UpdateMousePosition()
        {
            _currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

            _direction = _initialMousePosition - _currentMousePosition;
            _direction.Normalize();
            _indicator.Rotate(_direction);        
        }
```

`UpdateMousePosition()` is called once per frame when proper conditions are met. `_initialMousePosition` is the cached `Input.mousePosition` when player clicks on the object.

Comment: Could you specify what 'direction' is?

Comment: Well you tell it to take the `Vector3.up` vector as the up vector to rotate around .. so it is quite probable that your Y rotation will change ... How exactly are you calling that method?

Comment: @derHugo I've editted the question with additional information regarding how I call the method and what I mean by direction.

Comment: @whathm I've editted the post to answer your question

Comment: mouse position is in the `XY` plane with no dept on the Z axis ... so using `LookAt` with up axis `Vector3.up` seems odd here ... your object probably flips on Y depending if the target is left or right on the screen ..

Comment: @derHugo what would be the correct approach in that case?